# How can I calculate the distance traveled by an object, in a video?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I have a requirement where I need to calculate the distance traveled by a bird, in a video.

I am needing to calculate the `horizontal-shortest flight distance when the bird lands` and the `distance the bird traveled by air`.

I thought of using latitude and longitude, but it was not precise. I also thought of using computer vision, as well.

Can someone guide me in the right direction, and help me understand what kind of metadata is useful for me to solve this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 0):

VASCAR method could help you. Here's the [WIKIPEDIA link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VASCAR). For detailed implementation visit "*OpenCV Vehicle Detection, Tracking, and Speed Estimation*" by **Adrian Rosebrock**.